# mongodb run a function after each 10 minutes

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have a document in mongodb as below:

```
{
    id:1,
    requestType: {
        "api1": { 
            count:1,
            firstAttemptTime: 1514360898751.0
        },
        "api2": { 
            count:4,
            firstAttemptTime: 1514366897751.0
        }
    }
}
```

I want to write a function in mongoose that called every 10 minutes for removing an object from requestType based on firstAttemptTime key. for example after 10 minutes the document should be as below:

```
{
    id:1,
    requestType: {
        "api2": { 
            count:4,
            firstAttemptTime: 1514366897751.0
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want to remove data based on timestamp. It is possible to do that in MongoDB by setting TTL for a record and then there is no need to run functions periodically. You just create TTL index and specify after how many seconds document should be deleted. There is tutorial about this https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/expire-data/

Comment: I don't want to delete the document. I just want to remove a value of an object.

Comment: From the example, I can see that the id field could as well be inside api1 and api2 documents and then you can use this TTL expiring. Perhaps your provided example is not the full document you are using, but still, I think you should try to make your document and schemas so it could use TTL expiry and not long running function in MongoDB.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would work

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
var db = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost:port/db')
var newSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    id: Number,
    requestType: { type: {} },
    requestTypeList: { type: [] },
})
var model = db.model('newModel', newSchema)

setTimeout(function(){
    model.find({id: 1}, function(err, doc){
        // remove requestType properties first keyed value
        delete Object.keys(doc.requestType)[0]

        // or

        // remove requestType property's first value as an Array
        delete doc.requestTypeList[0] // I'd recomend because otherwise you'll be left with ever increasing key values like api90000000+ as the first key

        doc.save(function(err){
            if(!err){
                console.log('success :)')
            } else {
                console.log('oh oh')
            }
        })

    })
}, 600000) // 600000ms == 10 minutes

// es 5 or 6 idk..

setTimeout(()=>{
    model.find({id: 1}, (err, doc)=>{
        // remove requestType properties first keyed value
        delete Object.keys(doc.requestType)[0]

        // or

        // remove requestType property's first value as an Array
        delete doc.requestTypeList[0] // I'd recomend because otherwise you'll be left with ever increasing key values like api90000000+ as the first key

        doc.save((err)=>{
            if(!err){
                console.log('success :)')
            } else {
                console.log('oh oh')
            }
        })

    })
}, 600000) // 600000ms == 10 minutes
```

But I think maybe the TTL answer by Priidik might be more reliable